# Export WordPress from one domain to another domain

Tags: import, migration, export, domain

From one domain (foo.com), select export as WXR and import to (bar.com), also I manually uploaded wp-contents to the new location.

Everything is working, except the the images in the blog post still using the old domain.

1. How to solve it?
2. I have tried to upload into wp.com and they can auto update the images' location, but this does not work for self-hosted wordpress?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you **import** the WXR file to the WordPress install on the new domain, be sure to click the "**Download attachments**" checkbox that you are presented during the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/

Search for your old domain and replace with new... should search through all entries in your database and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Also check this out: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ It's not a plugin, just a script you load directly. Great tool and personally I migrate all my WP sites with it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option (the old domain still has to be functional and you can't do it from localhost to hosted) [Chip Bennet's solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/43914/21376) is probably the best, otherwise, I like [Velvet Blues Update Urls](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/).